# Delphi Colour Conversion Issue

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I just know I'm doing something really silly here, but I don't seem to be able to nut it out.

I'm having a first attempt at colouring a cell's background in a DBGrid, something I've avoided up until now. I have a field called "Buttoncolour" which holds a hex colour in the form "CCFFCC".  I have another column, the one I want to colour, called "ColourDescription".  I want to use the hex colour code to colour the canvas of the "ColourDescription" cell.

I have this code:

```
 procedure TProductForm.MDBGrid2DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TDBGColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
var
   CCol : String;
begin
   if column.fieldname = 'ColourDescription' then begin
      CCol := ProdGroupQuery.FieldByName('Buttoncolour').AsString;
      Canvas.Brush.Color:= StringToColor(CCol);
   end;
end;
```

I get a compile error telling me that something is not an integer value.  I assume that I've just got the whole thing wrong.   Can any of you kind people tell me what I SHOULD be doing, please?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is, that the error comes up (at runtime) from the `StringToColor` when you're trying to convert a non integer (non hexa) value. You should add `$` char at the beginning of that string (to be like `$CCFFCC`, so in your code it would be `Canvas.Brush.Color:= StringToColor('$' + CCol);`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is hex encoded. In order for StringToColor to decode that, you must prefix the string with a $ symbol.

```
Canvas.Brush.Color := StringToColor('$'+CCol);
```

This is made clear in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.StringToColor) which is always worth reading when you get stuck.

It may be simpler to call StrToInt instead of StringToColor since StringToColor does more than you need.

```
Canvas.Brush.Color := TColor(StrToInt('$'+CCol));
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that now, and the error goes away - but the colours aren't changing.  I've also added a font colour change when the record is marked as inactive and that doesn't work either.

Comment: First thing is that you're setting the color of a form's canvas brush, but you obviously want to change the cell color, so you should use either `MDBGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color` or `TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color`. The next thing is that you're not drawing anything. I think you'll need to fill the rectangle and draw the text by yourself (but maybe I'm wrong with the latter).

Comment: You asked how to solve your immediate problem, the runtime error because you passed the wrong value to StringToColor. This answers that. Please don't ask us to debug your entire program. Is it realistic for you to do so? For us to debug code that we cannot see? Anyway, the problem is probably down to you operating on the form's canvas rather than the control's canvas.

Comment: I've resolved that problem myself, and I accepted your original answer.  I wasn't actually asking you to resolve the second issue. But thanks anyway.  And thanks for pointing me at the Embarcadero documentation.  I'm still using Delphi 5, so I wouldn't naturally go there for answers ...

Comment: The Delphi 5 docs are quite decent. Select an indentifier in the IDE and press F1.

Comment: Would you have any idea about why the canvas brush colour in the grid is not the correct colour - even though it is using the hex codes passed to it?  I've checked that.  If I pass it CCFF33 I get a bright aqua instead of the light green I get when I pass that code to a button ...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea

Comment: That's because you are storing the color values in RGB notation whilst Delphi colors are expressed in BGR order. If the colors you have stored in your DB are web colors in RGB order, you might directly use the [`WebColorStrToColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.GraphUtil.WebColorStrToColor) function (without adding that `$` char), or swap those byte values of red and blue channels somehow.